# Connection between R and qlikview with opencpu

Tags: r, qlikview, opencpu

I want to create connection between R and QlikView using 'opencpu' package R.
I've seen some examples but I did not understand how to use the opencpu R package to create the connection between R and QlikView.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to provide a bit more detail in your question, such as what code have you written to try and establish the connection, and where is it going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[With its version 3.1 release, Qlik engine will be able to pass data in and out of both R and Python, including analysis context about a data set](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3118350/business-intelligence/qlik-to-add-r-python-support.html?token=%23tk.CTWNLE_nlt_computerworld_enterprise_apps_2016-09-09&idg_eid=300cd4d26427f9ff9d2002a69cc842d9&utm_source=Sailthru&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=ENTAPPSsept9&utm_term=computerworld_enterprise_apps#tk.CW_nlt_computerworld_enterprise_apps_2016-09-09)